# A question about the space $C(0,T;H)$ (or $C(0,T)$)

Tags: functional-analysis

$C(0,T;H)$ is the space of continuous functions $u:[0,T] \to H$ where $H$ is Hilbert. (Think of $C(0,T)$ if it helps). This space has norm
$$|u|_{C(0,T;H)} = \sup_{t \in [0,T]}|u(t)|_H.$$

I read a book in which it says:

> Let $u \in W$, where $W$ is some (Sobolev) Hilbert space. After some calculations, we see that
>   $$|{u}|_{C(0,T;H)} \leq |u|_W$$
>   hence $u \in C(0,T;H).$

Is this enough to conclude that $u$ is continuous? I thought the norm of $C(0,T;H)$ is one that we endow the space with and not a sufficient qualifier for belonging in the space.

Comment: you mean all $u\in W$, or just some $u$. I assume you are using embedding theorem.

Comment: Just some fixed $u$. Actually this is a property about embedding W into the continuous space but that isn't relevant..

Comment: Then I do not think $u\in C(0,T)$ is true.